# Add new line to admin action message

Tags: django, django-admin

How can you add a new line after, for example, triggering an admin action.

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.error(request, 'This is a line \n and this is another line')
```

I also tried with html tag  but didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to override part of [admin.base](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L67) template

In order to respect line breaks. There is builtin template tag [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr)

Overriden block in `base_site.html` will be:

```
<!-- The path and name for this file should be "templates/admin/base_site.html". -->
<!-- It overrides the original admin template and will be picked up by all of its children. -->
<!-- This template override has been verified for Django 1.11 and 2.0. -->

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block messages %}
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}
      {# added linebreaksbr here #}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message|capfirst|linebreaksbr }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock messages %}
```

Example taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/AndyLPK247/c4e04b0f71eff35affbeb3e4ad401232)

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

messages.error(request, mark_safe('This is a line <br> and this is another line'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @SYK
Ended up with a beautiful solution

```html
def clean_message(msg):
    # type: (unicode) -> Union[SafeBytes, SafeText]
    """
    cleans message to be fit for HTML
    """
    return mark_safe(msg.strip().replace("\n", "<br>"))
```